# Google Charts POLY problem with VS 2010 image map

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-visualization

Hi I am using http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/googleometer_chart.html

I have:

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=250x150&chd=s:egbdf&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,ff0000,12,0,lt|1,0000ff,10,1,lt&chm=o,000000,0,-1,10|V,000000,0,-1,1:15,,:4:10|H,000000,0,-1,3:9,,:8:17&chxl=0:|E|G|B|D|F" usemap ="#chart" />
           <map name='chart'>
                <area name='bar0_0' shape='POLY' coords= '124,440,124,499,143,440,143,498' href='#'>
                <area name='bar0_1' shape='RECT' coords='55,129,78,63' href='#'>
            </map>
```

When I use 'rect' for shape I can attach a click event etc but when I use 'poly' It doesn't work.

I've use a jQuery mouse position plug in to check the coords and they seem ok.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put image into something like paint and get it's coordinates, not the coordinates on the web page  Obviosuly, so it will still work anywhere on the page.